# Html: How to left-align text with centered image?

Tags: html, alignment

I need to do something like the following on my web page:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|Normal text                                                      |
|                                                                 |
|      Some text aligned to image left                            |
|      ----------------------------------------------------       |
|      |                  Centered image                  |       |
|      |                                                  |       |
|      ----------------------------------------------------       |
|                                                                 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have absolutely no idea how to do this. So far everything i have tried resulted in the text, that is supposed to be aligned with the left edge of the image, to be centered as well :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put the text and the image in a single `div` element. Center the div, and left-align the text within it.

Comment: I have tried that already...it results in the text aligned all the way to the left of the page and not the left edge of the image

Comment: @DTR: then try inheriting the 'centering' or the 'padding' from the div (or whichever way you centered it).

Answer (score 0):

1. Normal text --->give in normal way i.e without padding
2. Some text aligned to image left--->Give padding left
3. Centered image ----->give aligned center

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100%;">>
            <div style="text-align:left;">Normal Text</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100%;">
            <table style="width:80%;" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100%;">
                        <div style="text-align:left;">Some text aligned to image left</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100%;">
                        <image url=""></image>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Lets say, your images size: 800x600
HTML markup

```
<div id="content">
<img src="something...">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content img
{

    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-300px;
    margin-left:-400px;
}
```

**OR**

You can use image as background and

```
#content
{
    background-image:url('bg.png');
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

More about `background-position` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp